# NFS unavailable until NFS server restart

Tags: virtual-machine, nfs

I have quite a strange problem with NFS. I have two systems. One is my workstation, Ubuntu 13.04, linux kernel 3.8.0. Here I've got a directory with code I am working on: `/home/user/source`. The other is a virtual machine running on some remote server. It has Centos 6.3 and mounts the directory at `/opt/source`. The point is I have got a whole development environment there needed to run my code, but I want to store the code itself on my local machine for easier acces for Eclipse and other development tools.

Unfortunately, when I reboot my local machine, the NFS filesystem is unavailable on the virtual box until I run: `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart`. I cannot figure out why. Here's the only line in `/etc/exports` on my local machine:

```
/home/user/source 10.0.19.192(rw,sync,subtree_check)
```

And here's the line from `/etc/fstab` on virtual machine, where the NFS is described:

```
10.10.1.205:/opt/source /opt/WP nfs defaults,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: Is it possible that the NFS server is not started at boot?  Look for "nfsd" running after you reboot your local machine.

Comment: You're right, that was exactly the case. ^^ Could you tell me how to start nfs after boot? What I found myself on the internet is a bit mysterious. It seems I should add it to /etc/inittab, by there's no such file on my system, so I have no hint, how to write it.

By the way, shouldn't all scripts in /etc/init.d run sutomatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your NFS server wasn't started at boot time.  I think, even on Ubuntu 13.04, you can still manage this with the "rcconf" program:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf dialog
sudo rcconf
```

Then, check off nfs-kernel-server.

If for some reason this isn't working, try a similar process with the sysv-rc-conf package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately neither solution worked. `nfs-kernel-server` is checked for startup in both tools (in `sysv-rc-conf` I checked all runlevels possible even) and NFS still doesn't start at system startup.

Comment: Hi, this has worked for me in a similar problem [link](http://askubuntu.com/q/440224/25305)